# Duplicating a repeating table row in livecycle designer

Tags: javascript, livecycle

I have a table on one page in a Livecycle Designer form and would like the repeating row to duplicate to another table on a different page. I have this working on the first table on the first page to the table on the second using the exit event however, if the same information on the second table stays the same, because it is on the exit event, it does not copy to the new table on page 3.
I have this code in table 1 on page 1 on the exit event which works:

```
xfa.resolveNode("Month2.Performancegoals2.updates.details[" + this.parent.index + "]").projectName.rawValue = this.rawValue;
```

I thought this code would work using a button which unhides page 2

```
xfa.resolveNode("Month1.Performancegoals2.updates.details[" + this.parent.index + "]").projectName.rawValue = xfa.resolveNode("Month2.Performancegoals2.updates.details[" + this.parent.index + "]").projectName.rawValue
```

but this does not work. Actually when a value is placed in the field and the button is clicked, the entered value disappears.

Can anyone help? I'm out of time!

Answer (score 0):

OK, looks like you're assigning values backwards. Values in Javascript are assigned from right to left. So, whatever is on the right of the '=' get put into the left side.

e.g.,

```
x=5; //assigns the value 5 to x
y=x; //assigns whatever is in x to y
Month1 = Month2; //Month2 is assigned to Month1.
```

If Month2 is blank, then Month1 becomes blank